# Connecting JConsole to remote glassfish 4.1 / 4.1.1 via JMX

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-4, glassfish-4.1

GlassFish running on a host with a public ip address and jmx port 8986

On startup

```
JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://test.anahata.net.au:8986/jndi/rmi://test.anahata.net.au:8986/jmxrmi]]
```

When I try to connect via JConsole using test.anahata.net.au:8986 + user + password from another box, I get:

```
non-JRMP server at remote endpoint
```

If I try to connect using    service:jmx:rmi://test.anahata.net.au:8986/jndi/rmi://test.anahata.net.au:8986/jmxrmi

I get:

```
connection refused
```

domain.xml

```
> <admin-service system-jmx-connector-name="system"
> type="das-and-server">
>         <jmx-connector address="0.0.0.0" port="8986" name="system" auth-realm-name="admin-realm">
>           <ssl classname="com.sun.enterprise.security.ssl.GlassfishSSLImpl"
> client-auth="want" cert-nickname="s1as"></ssl>
>         </jmx-connector>
>         <property name="adminConsoleContextRoot" value="/admin"></property>
>         <property name="adminConsoleDownloadLocation" value="${com.sun.aas.installRoot}/lib/install/applications/admingui.war"></property>
>         <property name="ipsRoot" value="${com.sun.aas.installRoot}/.."></property>
>         <das-config></das-config>
>       </admin-service>
> 
> ...
> <jvm-options>-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=test.anahata.net.au</jvm-options>
```

I have a smilar setup on a different vm running gf 4.1.1 and a real SSL certificate and I can connect to the it using host:port but If I try to connect using
    service:jmx:rmi://host.com:8886/jndi/rmi://host.com:8886/jmxrmi

I get

```
java.rmi.ConnectIOException: non-JRMP server at remote endpoint
```

Has anyone got his head around this?

Answer (score 5):

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8686
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=myremoteip
```

Since glassfish 4 this is the only way.

Though I did managed to connect to glassfish's own jmx only before running asadmin enable-secure-admin.

turn on logging to FINE see if you got "LoginException during JMX auth"

```
javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.security
```

Anyway my conclusion was lot of headache, just use the jvm jmx above.

Comment: Disabling security is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

When you get this error:

```
java.rmi.ConnectIOException: non-JRMP server at remote endpoint
```

you are missing the keystore.jks file from glassfish/payara domain.